Explain this 1975 joke that blames severe weather on the SPD
Rudi Carrell's 1975 pop song "Wann wird's mal wieder richtig Sommer?" features light-hearted lyrics that pine for the warmer weather of yesteryear.  The last verse starts as follows:

Der Winter war der Reinfall des Jahrhunderts
Nur über tausend Meter gab es Schnee
Mein Milchmann sagt, "Dies Klima hier, wen wundert's
Denn Schuld daran ist nur die SPD!"

Can someone explain the humour in blaming the SPD (then part of Germany's ruling coalition) for the weather?  Is this just making light of (less educated) citizens' tendency to blame the government for everything – even things it has no control over – or is there a particular connection between the SPD and the climate that is being referenced here?

I (born 1961) see this as a joke about the "citizens' tendency to blame the government", no matter how illogical that is. And blaming the government for the weather had no plausible background back then.
In some part of the West-German society, the tendency was there to blame the SPD for everything that went wrong, especially as the switch from CDU-lead to SPD-lead government was not that long ago, and they argued "under the CDU everything was better than today".
Regarding climate change: the topic was already discussed in popular science publications, but with quite a different touch when compared with today. I remember having read an article back then that asked whether we were facing a new ice age or a hot climate.

This reminds me of the "Thanks Obama" meme in the US; see this video for a short history.

Today, a similar thing happens with the Green party, to an extend that the satire website Der Postillion offers a Greens Bashing Segue Generator. Put in any keyword, and the (supposed) KI generates a segue to why the Greens are horrible.

"Thanks Obama" became "Danke Merkel" in Germany.
